# Can we burn the maps tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Moving forward with this**

I don't see any value in the [maps](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps) tag. Permission to destroy it?

Comment: doitdoitdoitdoitdoitdoitdoit

Comment: I agree. Do eeet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done. [*turtle shades*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57Nf2.png)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhP3E.png]

NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

Comment: Looks like a mod went ahead and [deleted the tag](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps) :)

Comment: @Wipqozn Funny. To me it looks like there are 44 questions left.

Comment: oops, haha, I was in the featured tab :P